# Cordova plugin Geolocation is not working for Android version Kitkat

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, cordova-plugins

I have used the cordova plugin geolocation:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

**Install the plugin of cordova by command:**
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation

It is working fine in Android version Jelly Bean (Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 version 4.1.2 Jelly Bean, Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 version 4.1.2 Jelly Bean) with location off but is not working in Android version Kitkat (Samsung Note 2 version 4.4.2 Kitkat).

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);
       function geolocationSuccess(position) {
           var latlng = "Latitude :" + position.coords.latitude + ", Longitude :" + position.coords.longitude);
           $ionicPopup.alert({
               title: "User Current Location",
               subTitle: "Location",
               template: latlng
           });
       }

       function geolocationError(error) {
           $ionicPopup.alert({
                   title: "Pajhwok Location",
                   subTitle: "Error",
                   template: JSON.stringify(error)
           });
       }
```

Comment: `template: JSON.stringify(error)` want to print that error to the console / copy and paste it here?  Any other issues showing up in the debug console (since you are on kitkat you can use chrome dev tools!)

Comment: cordova geolocation plugin don't include native code anymore, so if it doesn't work is the webview's fault and there is nothing you can do

Comment: Cordova Geolocation plugin is working fine in case of location ON on android phones.. Error is also working after set timeout in option if location OFF

Answer (score 0):

As [@laughingpine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4099897/laughingpine) says, it would help to know exactly what the issue is you're encountering.

You said "It is working fine in Android version Jelly Bean (Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 version 4.1.2 Jelly Bean, Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 version 4.1.2 Jelly Bean) with location off but is not working in Android version Kitkat (Samsung Note 2 version 4.4.2 Kitkat)."

By this do you mean that on Android 4.4.2 the error callback is not being executed when location is off? Or that the error callback is being executed instead of success callback when location services is on? If so, please give us the error output.

If the latter, you can try explicitly setting maxAge and timeout, e.g.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, {maxAge: 30000, timeout: 60000});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Error and Success both are not being executed in case of location off on KitKat mobile (It is working in case of location on only). But on Jelly Bean, it is working in case of location off/on..

Comment: hey @SubhashKumar , have u solved your problem? I have encountered same problem.it is working on other android versions like android 5+, but it is giving timeout error in kitkat.

Comment: Hi @seyidyagmur, No but I have just added the "Location permission is required" for app and It's working fine in all version excluding KitKat. If user either set the Location/GPS - Off before/during run the app then I'm not giving the option/feature where location is required.